# android rxjava2 room get inserted object id in order to use it next query

Tags: android, rx-java2, android-room

I need proper approach to insert object to room and get rowId via rxjava2 way. For example: i have a Body entity

```
    long insertBody(Body body);
```

In viewmodel

```
    Body body = new Body(contactId, msgText);
    getCompositeDisposable().add(
            Single.fromCallable(() -> getDataSource().insertBody(body))
                    .subscribeOn(getSchedulerProvider().io())
                    .observeOn(getSchedulerProvider().ui())
                    .subscribe(bodyId -> onContinueNewMessage(msgId, conversationId, bodyId,
                            forwardBodyId, replyMsgId, createdTimestamp), Timber::e)
    );
```

The question is what if i write body object and get its rowId in multiple places? I need a method which insert body via rxjava way and return like Single... Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could consolidate the code you have inside the `add()` into methods.

For example:

```
public class Example {
    public static Single<Integer> insertBodySingle(Body body, DataSource dataSource) {
        return Single.fromCallable(() -> dataSource.insertBody(body));
    }

    public static Single<Integer> insertBodySingleThreaded(Body body, DataSource dataSource) {
        return insertBodySingle(body, dataSource)
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
    }
}
```

Then you can use these like this:

```
Example.insertBodySingle(body, dataSource).subscribe(bodyId -> )
```

Comment: i guess, you mean like this ```Example.insertBodySingleThreaded(body, dataSource).subscribe(bodyId -> )
```

Comment: i need some more clean code, any idea from other Android developers?